# Including python modules for PyInstaller?

Tags: python, scipy, pyinstaller

In one of my first attempts to package my python code into a .exe file, I experience issues with packaging and running code using the `scipy.weave` module. When I check my warnproject.txt, I see 1324 lines of warnings (a couple of lines included below)

```
W: no module named numpy.negative (top-level import by scipy.weave.size_check)
W: no module named numpy.asarray (top-level import by scipy.optimize.nonlin)
W: no module named termios (top-level import by tty)
W: no module named scipy.arange (conditional import by scipy.sparse.linalg.isolve.minres)
W: no module named numpy.polyder (top-level import by scipy.signal.signaltools)
W: no module named matplotlib.rcParams (top-level import by matplotlib.figure)
etc...
```

First question: why do I get this many warnings whereas the program partially runs ok?

Second question: how do I import these modules in a correct manner? In my `project.spec` file I have written `exe = EXE(..., a.binaries + [('scipy.weave', 'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages', 'PYMODULE')], ...)` but it can't find the module and will not package any file?

Comment: What do you mean your program runs partially ok?

Comment: @placeybordeaux the program runs up to the point that the `weave.inline` code comes in, it won't continue from thereon.

Answer (score 1):

One way to go is using the [hooks](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/v2.0/project/doc/Manual.html?format=raw#listing-hidden-imports) option for the Analysis object.
This forces the Analysis (the guy who compiles the list of dependencies among others) to consider that the modules from hooks have been imported, so are required.

```
a = Analysis(['myscript.py'], hookspath='/my/priv/hooks')
```

The [**hooks**](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/v2.0/project/doc/Manual.html?format=raw#listing-hidden-imports) file is  simple text file.

On the other hand, I have tons of such warnings, and my application runs on linux and windows without import related issues.